# Как и что отрисовывает этот SVG path?

Tags: svg

```
<svg width="258px" height="184px">
<path fill="#7AA20D" stroke="#7AA20D" stroke-width="9" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M248.761,92c0,9.801-7.93,17.731-17.71,17.731c-0.319,0-0.617,0-0.935-0.021c-10.035,37.291-51.174,65.206-100.414,65.206 c-49.261,0-90.443-27.979-100.435-65.334c-0.765,0.106-1.531,0.149-2.317,0.149c-9.78,0-17.71-7.93-17.71-17.731 c0-9.78,7.93-17.71,17.71-17.71c0.787,0,1.552,0.042,2.317,0.149C39.238,37.084,80.419,9.083,129.702,9.083    c49.24,0,90.379,27.937,100.414,65.228h0.021c0.298-0.021,0.617-0.021,0.914-0.021C240.831,74.29,248.761,82.22,248.761,92z" />
```

Смотрел MDN, но не удалось сопоставить ни с одним из шаблонов ввода координат. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает (атрибут d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот же описание](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-path/).

- `M<X>,<Y>`: переместить «перо» в заданную точку;
- `c<X0>,<Y0>,<X1>,<Y1>,<X2>,<Y2>`: построить кривую по трём точкам;
- `h<X>`: горизонтальная линия (с длиной в 0.021, тут она особо не заметна);
- `z`: закрыть фигуру.

В зависимости от регистра координаты воспринимаются либо как абсолютные (верхний регистр), либо как относительные (нижний). Разделители (запятые либо пробелы) между числами можно не ставить, если второе число отрицательное (парсер по «-» понимает, что предыдущее число кончилось).

*Если что, набросал [тут](http://acstuff.ru/u/svg-editor) простейший текстовый SVG-редактор, только ему нужен атрибут `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`. Ну и закрывающий тег, конечно.*

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы узнать что рисует это svg достаточно запустить его. Например в браузере, который понимает svg. Если у вас такой, то щёлкните кнопку "Выполнить код", которая расположена сразу под кодом.

```html
<svg width="258px" height="184px">
<path fill="#7AA20D" stroke="#7AA20D" stroke-width="9" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M248.761,92c0,9.801-7.93,17.731-17.71,17.731c-0.319,0-0.617,0-0.935-0.021c-10.035,37.291-51.174,65.206-100.414,65.206 c-49.261,0-90.443-27.979-100.435-65.334c-0.765,0.106-1.531,0.149-2.317,0.149c-9.78,0-17.71-7.93-17.71-17.731 c0-9.78,7.93-17.71,17.71-17.71c0.787,0,1.552,0.042,2.317,0.149C39.238,37.084,80.419,9.083,129.702,9.083    c49.24,0,90.379,27.937,100.414,65.228h0.021c0.298-0.021,0.617-0.021,0.914-0.021C240.831,74.29,248.761,82.22,248.761,92z" />
```

Как он это делает? Да пёс его знает. Может тут найдёте ответ https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=897

Comment: Спасибо. Я запускал в браузере. Получается лайм. Но мне непонятен процесс формирования значения для параметра d.